# Should I use Thread.sleep to be nice to other programs?

Tags: java

I usually write (smallish) games in Java using a main 'while' loop somewhat like this:

```
while(running) {
    time = getTime();
    if(time - oldTime > 0.01) {
        tick(time - oldTime);
        oldTime = getTime();
    } 
}
```

I do this to make the program have a maximum number of frames per second, but I've heard that Thread.sleep allows other threads to execute. Should I add in a Thread.sleep(1) (or some other low number of milliseconds) to allow other threads on the computer? It's more a question of good programming practice than performance, and it isn't really necessary, but I like making reliable and ungreedy programs.

Comment: Well it depends. Are you planning to do some other heavy computations while your game is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to do this.

All modern preemptive multitasking systems allocate time to other threads to allow them to execute.  You don't need to `sleep()` to accomodate this, unless you want to forcibly relinquish control to other threads for a certain period of time.

The only time you might want to do this is if you are hogging all of the cores on a multi-core system, and you want a long-running, computationally-intensive task to complete quietly in the background without discernibly affecting other operations taking place concurrently.

Comment: Additionally, Thread.sleep() only really affects other threads in the same VM. not other apps. For other apps, the OS scheduler is probably good enough to ensure fairness.

Answer (score 4):

I've had success building games that update the graphics using a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).  Read up on the benefits [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=160).  In general though, [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278242/104950) is correct, you don't *need* to do this.  I find that usually comes down to finding a sweet spot int terms of the game animations FPS, not about being nice to other processes.

Comment: See also [*Using Timers in Swing Applications*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/).